# Is it O.K. to use global data for multiple tests in the TDD cycle within the Google Test framework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, googletest

I have just started using Gtest, and I am writing tests that look like this:

```
TEST(testFamily, specificTest) {
     initData data; 
     ASSERT_TRUE(boolean_algorithm(data)); 
}
```

The problem is that my testing code gets unnecesarily bloated because I have a lot of tests that can use the same data, so the line:

```
 initData data;
```

shouldn't be repeated for each test. I know that tests should be independent of each other and in that aspect, using something like a constant global

```
const initData data;
```

brings questions like "Are you sure your tests won't modify the global test data?". Should i keep initializing the same test configuration for each test? Sometimes the initialized test data requires much more code than one line....

Comment: Most unit test frameworks provide a initialization method that will be run before each test and a clean up method that will be run after each test. Does google test not provide this?

Comment: @DanPantry: the data that I require is library specific. Its a bunch of geometrical objects, and the library does intersection, collision detection, etc. There are many special (degenerate) cases involved like a point collision. So for a same point collision, I can test if the bounding boxes intersect, does the separation algoirthm recognize the special case, and is the calculated intersection a point. Same data == bunch of tests. I'll probably follow the advice of BЈовић below - encapsulate test data initialization + re-use the code locally in each TEST function, without repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok, but I would create that object in the testing class, rather then in the global scope (like explained in [Test Fixtures: Using the Same Data Configuration for Multiple Tests](http://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html#same-data-multiple-tests)).

For example, like this :

```
initData CreateData() 
{
    initData d;
    // set values
    return d;
}

class testFamily : public testing::Test
{
public:
    testFamily() :
            data( CreateData()  )
    {
    }
    ~testFamily()
    {
    }

    initData data;
};

TEST_F( testFamily, specificTest )
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(boolean_algorithm(data)); 
}
```

Now, the data structure is calculated (or set) only in one place (`CreateData()` function).

Comment: this is what I was thinking of as well. The data is small and the tests run extremely quickly, but the configuration of the tests is tedious. It's a geometrical library, so you can imagine how fun it must be to set up special cases e.g. for intersecting geometrical objects. I'll create the test library with test classes and then I can re-use the test configuration in TEST without duplicating code. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't used googletest before! But saying that...

It's never a good idea to share modifiable data between unit tests. A unit test should independant of any other unit tests and it shouldn't matter which order you run the unit tests in. The risk that you run by sharing data is that as a side-effect (or consequence) of data that is modified a test passes (or fails). A unit test should also be very quick to run, if it takes too long the test will be discarded or never run (and so pretty pointless).

But now the question is, what if it's expensive to create the test data? If your test data is dependant on a resource outside of the unit test (database, network connection etc) what you are actually doing is integration testing and these can be slow to run (and brittle if the data is not mananged correctly by resetting it after every test run).

I don't have any issue with re-using static (non-modifiable) data in unit tests (and setting this up when the test suite loads) but re-using data that may have be modified in some way is a big no-no.

Another question that perhaps you should ask yourself is,could I look to Mock or Stub out the objects I need?

Comment: very good suggestions, but not sure how much this answers the question

Comment: @BЈовић Thanks! I think what I'm trying to say is, specifically in regards to the question asked in the title, is that No, I don't think it's a good idea to use modifiable global data in a group of tests  if it may result in unintended side effects. Static data is fine of course but as you suggest in your answer better if it's not global but scoped to the test group.

Answer (score 1):

***To reuse data between tests***

If your tests are not modifying your test data and you want to avoid regenerating that multiple times, then [the recommended method](http://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite) is to use `static` members in your test fixture:

1. Declare the data to be reused as a static member variable in your fixture class
2. Define and initialize the static variables outside the class as usual
3. Add a `static void SetUpTestSuite()` method to the fixture class for setup and, optionally, a `static void TearDownTestSuite()` method for tear-down.

Example code from the documentation:

```
class FooTest : public testing::Test {
 protected:
  // Per-test-suite set-up.
  // Called before the first test in this test suite.
  // Can be omitted if not needed.
  static void SetUpTestSuite() {
    // Avoid reallocating static objects if called in subclasses of FooTest.
    if (shared_resource_ == nullptr) {
      shared_resource_ = new ...;
    }
  }

  // Per-test-suite tear-down.
  // Called after the last test in this test suite.
  // Can be omitted if not needed.
  static void TearDownTestSuite() {
    delete shared_resource_;
    shared_resource_ = nullptr;
  }

  // You can define per-test set-up logic as usual.
  void SetUp() override { ... }

  // You can define per-test tear-down logic as usual.
  void TearDown() override { ... }

  // Some expensive resource shared by all tests.
  static T* shared_resource_;
};

T* FooTest::shared_resource_ = nullptr;

TEST_F(FooTest, Test1) {
  ... you can refer to shared_resource_ here ...
}

TEST_F(FooTest, Test2) {
  ... you can refer to shared_resource_ here ...
}
```

***To reuse code to generate the data***

Follow BЈовић's answer or the [docs on test fixtures](http://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html#same-data-multiple-tests).

Note that each test will use a separate instance of the fixture class!

Answer (score 0):

I think your concern comes down to two things :

- Worry that you're unnecessarily consuming memory, or
- Worry about unnecessarily repeating code.

Keep in mind that the reason tests should be separate is because if need be, they should be able to be run independently. In that respect, it's okay to keep re-initializing the same context for each test.

If you're worried about test-code maintainability, one idea would be that if you have a lot of tests that have a very similar context, then all the initialization stuff can be put into a common function that is just invoked. That will have the added advantage of keeping the code of the individual tests clean.